# MySQL Queries Pegging Server Resources -- Indexes aren't being used

Tags: mysql, joomla, phpmyadmin

I took on a volunteer project a few years ago.  The site is set up with Joomla, but most of the articles are rendered with php scripts that pull info from non-Joomla tables.  The database is now almost 50MB and several of the non-Joomla tables have 60,000+ rows -- I had no idea it would get this big.  Even just pulling up the list of the articles that contain these scripts takes a long time -- and right now there are only about 30 of them.  I initially thought the problem was because I'm on dial-up, so everything is slow, but then we started getting "resources exceeded" notices, so I figured I better find out what's going on.  It's not a high traffic site -- we get less than 2,000 unique visitors in any given month.

In one particular instance, I have one table where the library holdings (books, etc.) are listed by title, author, pub date, etc.  The second table contains the names mentioned in those books.  I have a Joomla! article for each publication that lists the names found in that book.  I also have an article that lists all of the names from all of the books.  That is the query below -- but even the ones for the specific books that pull up only 1,000 or so entries are very slow.

I originally set up indexes for these tables (MyISAM), but when I went back to check, they weren't there.  So I thought re-configuring the indexes would solve the problem.  Not even -- and according to EXPLAIN, they aren't even being used.

One of my problematic queries is as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM pub_surnames
WHERE pub_surname_last REGEXP '^[A-B]'
ORDER BY pub_surname_last, pub_surname_first, pub_surname_middle
```

EXPLAIN gave:

```
id 1
select_type SIMPLE
table pub_surnames
type ALL
possible_keys NULL
key NULL
key_len NULL
ref NULL
rows 56422
Extra Using where; Using filesort
```

Also, phpmyadmin says "Current selection does not contain a unique column."

All of the fields are required for this query, but I read here that it would help if I listed them individually, so I did.  The table contains a primary key, and I added a second unique index containing the primary key for the table, as well as the primary key for the table that holds the information about the publication itself.  I also added an index for the ORDER BY fields.  But I still get the same results when I use EXPLAIN and the performance isn't improved at all.

I set these tables up within the Joomla! database that the site uses for connection purposes and it makes it easier to back everything up.  I'm wondering now if it would help if I used a separate database for our non-Joomla tables?  Or would that just make it worse?

I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: You have one article with all of the names in all of the books? I'm not clear how that relates to the query.  What do you mean by "he list of the articles that contain these scripts"?      It really seems to me (just reading this) that what you are saying about the "articles" doesn't make sense.   Do you have a key for your the pub_surnames table?   Also you don't say what Joomla version you are on, but that will make a difference for the solution.

Comment: The articles contain the php scripts that select the surnames that are indexed for a particular book based on the HoldingID number.  Those run quickly enough.  It's the one above that's problematic.  Yes -- all the tables have primary keys.

Comment: Joomla is v. 2.5  I have a menu item that lists all the articles in a category -- "Indexes."  Each book has an article of it's own that lists the surnames that have been indexed for that book.  So far, I have about 30 of them done.  There are more -- there are about 1,200 books -- but I don't want to do any more until I figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Why would you have php scripts in articles? Put them into plugins. Articles are for text not code.  Just the order that things happen in ... from what you are saying you are doing this in the middle of rendering a page, of course that is slow. And it sounds like you are not caching either.    I really think you need to have a database with a field for book and a row for each name mentioned.     Also if you have the text in articles just let finder index them and do the queries with that, it will be way faster.  Don't do the search each time, let finder do it once properly.

Comment: I have caching disabled while I'm messing with things but yes, in practice, caching is enabled.  The library's catalog is constantly being updated and changed.  Maintaining the articles would take on a life of it's own.  I don't understand your comment about the database.

Comment: No, I mean are you caching the list of books and names when you generate  them in your php scripts?  What do you mean maintaining the articles would take on a life of its own? Why wouldn't you be automating that?  That's what I'm saying. Write a script to update your data, don't don't do it when a user comes and reads the a page. You should be doing that with a chron job; write a simple joomla CLI to get the data and then write the data into a proper database table or if you want i guess push them into a specific article (still not sure what that is doing). Code might help make it clearer.

Comment: Ah! Yes!  I see.  I'll work on that this weekend.  Thanks!

Comment: I've started looking into the issues raised in your comments, and to my mind, the correct answer to my question is, "You're doing it wrong!"  If you want to post that, I'll be happy to mark it.  :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are probably approaching this the wrong way. Probably it was the quick way to get it done when you first set it up, but now that the data has grown you are paying the price.

It sounds like you are recreating a massive list "inside" an article each time a page is rendered. Even though the source data is constantly being updated you would probably be better off storing the results. (Assuming I understand your data structure correctly.) Not knowing exactly what your php scripts are doing makes it a little complicated .. it could be that it would make more sense to actually make a very simple component to read the data from the other tables but I'll assume that doesn't make sense.

Here's what I think you might want to do.
Create a cron job (really easy to make a script using Joomla, go take a look at the jacs respository) and use it to run whatever your php is doing. You can schedule it once a day or once an hour or every 10 minutes, whatever makes sense.

Save the results.  These could go into a data base table or you could cache them in the file system. Or both. Or possibly have the script update the articles since they seem to be fixed (you aren't adding new ones etc)

Then when  the user comes you just want to either read the article if you stored there or you want to have a component that renders the results or make a plugin that will manage the queries for you.  You should not be doing queries directly from inside an article layout, it's just wrong, even if no one knows it's there. If you have to run queries, use a content plugin similar to maybe the profile plugin, which does the queries in the right place architecturally.

Not knowing the exact purpose of what you are doing, it's hard to advise more, but I think if you are managing searches for people you'd likely be better off creating a way to use finder to index and search the results.

Comment: Thank you for the help on this.  Your suggestions have given me a lot to look at and the performance is already improved.  You're right -- I was doing it wrong.  Thanks!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check out below suggestions

1. Try changing your database engine to InnoDB which will work better for large datasets.
2. Also use RegEx alternative, which is used in "WHERE" part of query which hugely affects queries execution time.
3. Instead selecting all the columns with "*" just select needed columns.

Comment: I didn't use InnoDB because I needed full-text search.  I'm selecting all of the columns in this particular case because I do need all of them.  I took a quick peek at the RegEx issue and am going to look into this more to see if it helps.  Thank you.

Comment: Try changing REGEX part and make a comment if it optimizes the execution time

Comment: Actually, it turns out the REGEXP is faster in this instance.  Thanks!